# Add specific website to Chrome's New Tab Page

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is there a way to explicitly add a URL to Chrome's new tab page dial pad?

[image]

Comment: See my answer here: [Can I restore a deleted site to the Chrome search homepage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/118783)

Comment: I've voted to close this question, can't delete it no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not look like there is a way to specifically add a URL for it to appear in the new tab page - generally that page is Most Visited (depending on what you have set to appear).

Would be a very useful feature instead of accessing bookmarks but you could create a bookmarks folder and add you important sites there - should be two clicks away at most.

Here are a possible of work around:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VnDvOnYvZrQ

Comment: That workaround doesn't work. I think I unwillingly deleted one of the dialpad items, and Chrome avoids re-adding it again, so there is only a way to explicitly delete, but no means to explicitly add.

Comment: Yeah I find it annoying - hopefully they will add the functionality in a future update.

Comment: If you open the desired site, then delete all sites from the new tab page, for some obscure reason the only site that will show up there is the last active tab. An incredibly stupid behavior of course.